# Replace Orbeon Form with a new one asynchronously via AJAX

Tags: ajax, forms, asynchronous, orbeon

I am using Orbeon forms with Hybris. We have several pages linked together where a user needs to go through them in a sequence (checkout process).

The **content** of the Orbeon form is **dynamically** being determined based on **actions from previous steps**. E.g.

*If user adds Product A to the cart on the step 1, only two fields will be visible on the form located on step 2, if he adds another (Product B) on step 1, one more field should be visible on the form.*

I am using certain preprocessor class which prefills some of the hidden fields on the form and then the logic for dynamic display is on the Form itself, based on those hidden fields. This works in a simple scenario when moving back and forth, through the steps.

However, the problem is that I need to have a **HTML** **Mini-cart** displayed on the page as well (not part of Orbeon Form), which can also **trigger adding/removing of the products asynchronously**.

*So while I am on step 2 where the form is displayed, the user can also remove/re-add some of the products -> therefore, this needs to trigger asynchronous re-rendering of the form and change the display of the form (with new fields added or removed).*

I'm using AJAX for this async stuff and the problem I am facing is that a lot of Orbeon-specific Javascript files and variables is being generated when the page loads for the first time, and some random FormID is used. This FormID is different when I retrieve the new form from the back-end and when trying to replace the HTML content I'm getting various errors in the console, because old Form id is used all over the place.

Does anyone have any suggestion if this could be achieved and how to approach this problem?

**Update**: Example of "hidden" field *glass-coverage-selected*

`<xf:instance id=""fr-form-instance"" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes=""#all"">
    <form>
       <glass-coverage-selected/>
       <section-1>
            <massive-exterior-walls/>
       </section-1>
...`

Later, a bind is created:

```
<xf:bind id=""section-40-bind"" ref=""section-40"" name=""section-40"" relevant=""instance('fr-form-instance')/glass-coverage-selected = 'yes'"">
   <xf:bind id=""previous-glass-insurance-bind"" ref=""previous-glass-insurance"" name=""previous-glass-insurance"">
       <xf:required id=""validation-156-validation"" value=""true()""/>
</xf:bind>
```

And that bind is used to control the visibility of certain section:

```
<fr:section id=""section-40-control"" bind=""section-40-bind"">
     <xf:label ref=""$form-resources/section-40/label""/>
     <fr:grid>
         <xh:tr>
            <xh:td>
               <xf:select1 id=""previous-glass-insurance-control"" appearance=""full"" bind=""previous-glass-insurance-bind"" class=""previous-insurance"">
                   <xf:label ref=""$form-resources/previous-glass-insurance/label""/>
                   <xf:hint ref=""$form-resources/previous-glass-insurance/hint""/>
                   <xf:help ref=""$form-resources/previous-glass-insurance/help""/>
                   <xf:alert ref=""$form-resources/previous-glass-insurance/alert[1]"" validation=""validation-156-validation""/>
                   <xf:alert ref=""$form-resources/previous-glass-insurance/alert[2]""/>

                   <xf:itemset ref=""$form-resources/previous-glass-insurance/item"">
                       <xf:label ref=""label""/>
                       <xf:value ref=""value""/>
                       <xf:hint ref=""hint""/>
                    </xf:itemset>
               </xf:select1>
           </xh:td>
       </xh:tr>
    </fr:grid>
</fr:section>
```

Comment: I think we'll need to find a way for you to be able to do those changes to the form without having to reload it. Reloading the form in-place is in theory possible, but creates a number of problems, and isn't supported.

Comment: You're saying that upon users interaction with your "mini-cart" you need to add/remove products. What does the adding/removing product look like at the forms level? It maps to setting some of those hidden fields you're talking about to different values?

Comment: Yes, when a user clicks somewhere in the mini-cart he can add/remove the products. This information (which products are in the cart) I use to prefill certain hidden field(s) [please see update above, field _glass-coverage-selected_]. After that, I use the value of this hidden field to control the visibility of certain section(s).

This is all done in the back-end, before the form is rendered and displayed. Do you mean there is a way to manipulate with value of this hidden fields on the front-end in a way that visibility of dependent sections is also handled?

Comment: OK, got it, so indeed, you can manipulate the values of those fields in JavaScript, in the browser. When you're referring to "hidden fields", I imagine you've hidden them by putting `false()` under *Visibility* for the field. If you do this, for security, the value of the field isn't even sent to the browser by Orbeon Forms, and it can't be set from JavaScript. Instead, if you want to be able to set the value from JavaScript, you need to hide the control with CSS. The simplest way to do this is to add the class `xforms-disabled` in the Control Settings dialog.

Comment: Then, assuming the name of the control in Form Builder is `my-control`, you can write `var control = ORBEON.jQuery('*[id $= "my-control-control"]'); ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue(control.attr('id'), '42');`. Note the `-control` added at the end of the name of the control. And to test this first, I recommend you don't put the CSS class, so you can more easily see if setting the value works. Would this work for you?

Comment: Hi @avernet, great, it works. Thank you very much for the help. You can post it as an answer, to mark this one as solved. One more question regarding the syntax you used above - is there some kind of documentation for this, where I could get more info on possible ways to manipulate with Orbeon Forms through JavaScript? Or at least some general description of the items, methods and parameters?

Comment: P.S. I'm also looking into that so I can trigger the saving of the form from JS

Comment: Very good, I'm glad this works for you! I've posted a slighted edited version of my comment as an answer, and you'll find at the end a link to the relevant documentation. To do a save, the simplest is most likely to trigger a click on the save button. e.g. in XQuery. Would and if you don't want the Orbeon Forms' save button to be visible to end-users, you can hide it with CSS. Would this work for you?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I'll take a look into this XQuery triggering, I think it would work. Thanks!

Comment: Got it. It will work ;). But of course, just let me know if you're having any trouble with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the values of form fields in JavaScript, in the browser. If you want to set the value of "hidden fields", you make sure that those fields as not hidden by putting `false()` under *Visibility* for the field in Form Builder. If you do this, for security reasons, the value of the field isn't even sent to the browser by Orbeon Forms, and it can't be set from JavaScript. Instead, to be able to set the value from JavaScript, you need to hide the control with CSS. The simplest way to do this is to add the class `xforms-disabled` for that field in the Control Settings dialog.

Then, assuming the name of the control in Form Builder is `my-control`, in JavaScript you can write `var control = ORBEON.jQuery('*[id $= "my-control-control"]'); ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue(control.attr('id'), '42');`. Note the `-control` added at the end of the name of the control. And to test this first, I recommend you don't put the CSS class, so you can more easily see if setting the value works.

For the documentation on the above `setValue()` and other JavaScript APIs, see the page [Client-side JavaScript API](http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/client-side-javascript-api.html).